# MultiThread paused and resume pthread.h

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, resume

I have 500 thread have id from 0 -> 499. I want when I type p[thread_ip] or r[thread_id] the thread have id thread_id will be pause or resume. I use mutex and condition variable, something like this :

```
while(1)
{
   while(!run) pthread_cond_wait(&con, &mutex);
}
```

pause:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
run = 0;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

resume :

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
run = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

When I have 500 thread, do I need to have 500 condition variables and 500 mutex?

Comment: I think 500 globals (an array of 500 chars for example) and 500 semaphores would work.  If you wanted to use 500 mutex + 500 conditions instead of 500 semaphores it should work also.  I don't think you are using your mutexes correctly, though.

Comment: I miss lock and unlock mutex in the thread function.